# Get Value of Key in Class Object Which has classes inside and some Generic List

Tags: c#

I have a class object which looks like this. I have like 4 main objects as you see. Each object has Data with Generic List. I want to get properties from that generic lists and to get the value of any key I will wish for.  I want to be able to get any value of any key. Is that even possible? Or do I have to use foreaches and so on?

I tried using Reflection but don't know if I did correctly because it is always null.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "person")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "bank-products-info")]
public class Bankproductsinfo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "person")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fullInfo")]
    public string FullInfo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = response.Person.Data.GetType().GetProperty("name");
string name = (string)(pi.GetValue(response, null));
```

The Problem here is that in Data there will be Key and Value and i Need Some keys only for example in Person.Data List there will be Key like "name" i want to get it.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few problems with this code. First of all I think you have the wrong structure. Basically with your `Data` class and the `List<Data>` it seems you're trying to achieve `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` functionality (or would a person be allowed to have multiple `Data` objects with "name" as their `Key`?).

That said if we stick to this structure, there is no need for reflection here, you can just use LINQ:

```
var response = new Bankproductsinfo
{
    Person = new Person
    {
        Data = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data
            {
                Key = "name",
                Text = "John Doe"
            }
        }
    }
};

var name = response.Person?.Data?.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "name")?.Text;
```

If the `response` has a `Person` and that `Person` has `Data` and that `Data` has atleast 1 `Data` object with `Key == "name"` then this will give the `Text` of the first `Data` object with `Key == "name"` and `null` otherwise.

Comment: unfortunatly this is the body they give me. and yes Data can be multiple. For example i have Products class which has Items which has Data of List<Data> . And to get what i want i ahve to write 2 foreach + i have to check always that data is not null and i dont like that. thats why i wanted to know if there is a way to get by key names

Comment: @lukacecxladze yeah the line `var name = response.Person?.Data?.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "name")?.Text;` should do that for you. Is this not working for you?